# Is there an existing name for this hook-sword-like shortsword design?

Tags: weapons, history, terminology

I was looking to add this premise of a weapon for a character I'm writing. I remembered this style existed in Breath of the Wild as an Eightfold Blade. While it does have a hilt, it is only a very small circular guard with no ricasso. The main thing that I'm focusing on is the name of swords that have the little hook mini-blade near the hilt, *similar* to a hook sword in strategy yet more simplified.

[image: Eightfold Blade]

At first, I thought the hook was a Schilden, but Schilden tend to have their tips pointing perpendicular to the blade (below), and not like the Eightfold Blade in the picture.

[image: Greatsword featuring a Schilden]

Is there any historical name for this type of sword, or is it just fantasy? If so, what is the closest historical classification?

[image: Eightfold Blade]

Comment: I suspect the exact configuration is pure fantasy, as it would be easier to have the upswept bit be part of the crossguard rather than the blade.

Comment: So what is *"hook sword .. strategy"* then? // @Daron is likely right about the depiction probably being pure fantasy, but that aside the only reasonable use for what's shown is as a tool to catch an opponents blade and then either break it or twist it from the opponents grasp with a twist of the wrist.

Comment: Since you are asking purely about real world weapons, and your example is not from a story of your own creation, this probably a better question to ask on history.se ... now if you wish to know how one might prefer to use such a weapon, WB could be on topic since the original martial arts behind this style of weapon are lost to time.

Comment: I'm not entirely sure this question deserves close votes.... Identification of technology is only slightly different than asking a real-world question about technology. Granted, I no longer agree that we should permit real-world questions in the context of the current policy... but could a close voter explain exactly how this isn't about worldbuilding (remember that real-world question policy...)?

Comment: I was trying to see if this design existed in the first place, but now that I know it does, this question is probably better suited on martial arts.se

Answer (score 6, accepted):

### There's similar weapons in Japan

#### Jitte

A hook on a blugeon sword-like item is well known as a [Jitte](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jitte). The hook is a parrying device and to disarm an opponent.
[image]^

#### kabutowari

An offshoot of the normal sword is the [Kabutowari](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kabutowari), literally "Helmet-breaker" or "Skull-breaker". The more common type with a hook is the truncheon type, which is similar to the blunt [Tekkan](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tekkan). The hook is a parrying device.
[image]

Dirk type Kabutowari may have some sharpness and a piercing tip, but typically the hook is on the backside as with all of them.
[image]

In either case the hook is formed out of the same piece of metal.

#### Sai

Similar, but a piercing weapon, is the [Sai](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sai_(weapon)). Usually they have two hooks to catch blades, but one hook and one guard style exist. It is very similar to the [Tepki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tekpi) and related to it. The hooks are used to catch and then twist a weapon from the attacker's hands.
[image]

### There is a popular weapon in China

Sai have found their way into Chinese martial arts, but china also has its own styles:

#### Hook Sword/shuang gou

[shuang gou](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hook_sword) feature hooks on either side of the grip, forming a parrying surface and hilt guard, and a hooked tip. They are used in pairs to disarm the enemy.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I will add to Trish's answer (**Edit:** The image is now part of Trish's answer proper) that if you follow the Wikipedia link to Kabutowari, you get a picture of a supposed metal one of those:

[image]

Looks pretty real to me. Guess I was wrong about the exact configuration. I wonder how they attach the hook part.

Comment: it's not attached, it is forged in one part.

Comment: @Trish That sounds like a something you need to be highly skilled to do properly.

Comment: Actually it's rather simple, if you cut out of a larger piece of plate. And drawing out a hook from a simple bar is not much harder than forming a tang^^

Comment: @Trish I will defer to your expertise :-)